# How to generate a new response during inbound call in go?

Tags: go, twilio

Let say my app is in a inbound call with a default
 Hello There 
And I want to add a do a new response after 10 seconds.
 This is a new speech after ten seconds

Is it possible to do it?

I know it works in outbound call but I am not sure about inbound call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.